# Select left entity from left join with one column based on right entity

Tags: linq-to-sql

These are two simplified models:

```
public class Member {
    public int MemberId
    [Ignore]
    public bool IsActive
    ...
}

public class User {
    public int UserId
    public int MemberId
    ...
}
```

`Member.IsActive` is not mapped to to table, but Member is effectively active if there is an entry in User with same MemberId.

Because models are big, I would prefer to do simple return and avoid projection by setting all properties of Member manually

Pseudo select:

```
var members = from m in _dbContext.Members
              join u in _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.MemberId == m.MemberId).DefaultIfEmpty()
              select m --> with some magic on m. IsActive
```

I don't want anonymous object like `select new {Member = m, IsActive = u.Whatever}`

From my research this seems impossible, at least without materializing entities before select. But, most of these answers are quite old and I was wondering is there an easy way today?

Comment: Create a navigation property Member.User and use Where(m => m.User != null).

Comment: Thank you, but I am not trying to filter data. I am trying to "left join" two entities into one and return that one without having to write verbose property mapping in `Select new ...`

Comment: That's not possible. There's no SELECT * in LINQ. Still, a navigation property would be beneficial.